# What's difference between FISH and SFTP?

Tags: ssh, sftp, fish-protocol

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between SFTP, SCP and FISH protocols?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8707/whats-the-difference-between-sftp-scp-and-fish-protocols)

I use SSH for remote file systems access. And I use Krusader file manager. Krusader offers a choice of FTP, SMB, FISH and SFTP connection protocols, and both FISH and SFTP work with an SSH server. What's the difference among FISH and SFTP?

PS: I don't specify Krusader in the question title because Midnight Commander, for example, supports FISH as well, so that FISH can be something not limited to Krusader.