# What's the difference between SFTP, SCP and FISH protocols?

Tags: ssh, scp, sftp, fish-protocol

I used to think SCP is a tool to copy files over SSH, and copying files over SSH is called SFTP, which is itself a synonym to FISH.

But now as I was looking for a Total Commander plugin to do this in Windows, I've noticed that on its page it says "Allows access to remote servers via secure FTP (FTP via SSH). Requires SSH2. This is NOT the same as SCP!".

If it's not the same then what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: This is an extension of a [previous question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/whats-difference-between-fish-and-sftp). (@Ivan: it would have been helpful to mention this.)

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/134901/133844

Answer (score 92, accepted):

[SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) isn't the FTP protocol over ssh, but an extension to the SSH protocol included in SSH2 (and some SSH1 implementations).  SFTP is a file transfer protocol similar to FTP but uses the SSH protocol as the network protocol (and benefits from leaving SSH to handle the authentication and encryption).

SCP is only for transferring files, and can't do other things like list remote directories or removing files, which SFTP does do.

FISH appears to be [yet another protocol](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/mc/mc/vfs/README.fish?view=markup) that can use either SSH or RSH to transfer files.

---

UPDATE (2021/03/09): According to the release notes of [OpenSSH 8.0/8.0p1 (2019-04-17)](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.0):

> The **scp** protocol is outdated, inflexible and not readily fixed. We
> recommend the use of more modern protocols like sftp and rsync for
> file transfer instead.

Comment: Worth adding: there's also FTPS, which is FTP over TLS.

Comment: @mikemaccana you can then add FTPES witch is the possibility to use ftps explicitly over a regular ftp connection

Comment: Hmm, second sentence "SFTP is a file transfer protocol similar to FTP but uses the SSH protocol as the network protocol" sounds like "FTP protocol over ssh", which is negated in the first sentence. Just sounds a bit confusing to me... Perhaps useful to say what is the same and what isn't.

Comment: "SCP is only for transferring files, and can't do other things"  – On the contrary, SCP can do *anything*. By supplying an "unfortunate" remote filename you can run arbitrary shell code. This can be creatively (mis)used ([example](https://superuser.com/a/1634882/432690)), but in most cases there is no point of using `scp` for this because it's easier to pass the desired shell code via `ssh`. Nowadays `scp` uses SFTP, but the SCP *protocol* itself still can inject code. (Note I use SCP for the protocol and `scp` for the executable, like in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1733992/432690).)

Answer (score 59):

The SSH protocol creates a secure tunnel through which you can transfer a bidirectional stream, and you can use that stream to connect any two processes you like.

The most familiar two processes would be a shell (at the server) and an interactive terminal emulator (at the client). That's what you're using when you ssh to a server and type commands at the remote shell's prompt.

**SCP** is file transfer done using only that shell and a remote command. In SCP, once the client is connected to the server, and all the authentication and authorization has been done, the client sends the remote shell a command like `scp -f myfile.txt`, which just writes the contents of the file myfile.txt to the stream (for the client to read) or `scp -t myfile.txt` which reads from the stream and writes to myfile.txt.

You'll notice that -f and -t (for "from" and "to") are not in the scp manpages. They are considered internal. There is a lightweight acknowledgement scheme, and a scheme for transferring directories by wrapping the file contents in simple headers. But for the most part SCP is a basic matter of writing the bytes of the file onto the SSH tunnel, letting SSH deal with complicated stuff like compression and integrity.

**SFTP** is a much more complex file transfer protocol, which again is tunnelled through SSH.

In SFTP both requests and responses are binary-encoded packets with names like "SSH_FXP_OPEN", "SSH_FXP_STAT", "SSH_FXP_READ", "SSH_FXP_DATA", "SSH_FXP_CLOSE".

One interesting feature of the protocol is that commands can be pipelined, and responses may come in any order. This can mean that sessions spend less time waiting on responses, and there are opportunities to optimise concurrent transfers from one server with data-sources of various speeds -- although I don't know to what extent those opportunities have been taken.

SFTP has commands to do many things that SCP doesn't address; like delete, rename, truncate, move, etc.

All the details are available in an [IETF Draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13).

It's worth noting that newer SSH packages replace the user `scp` binary with a symlink to the SFTP binary. This SFTP has the look and feel of scp, but under the covers it's using the SFTP protocol.

> *Citation* --  O'Reilly *SSH: The Secure Shell, The Definitive Guide*, section 5.7 "Subsystems":
>
> WARNING: Don't remove the subsystem-sftp line from sshd2_config: it is required for scp2 and sftp to work. Internally, both programs run ssh2 -s sftp to perform file transfers.

**Fish** is an interesting piece of history. Let's say you want to transfer files over SSH, but your remote system doesn't have SCP. Or perhaps you want to do more sophisticated file operations than SCP, but your remote system doesn't have SFTP. Neither of those scenarios are likely today, but when Fish was invented, they were.

So the developers of the client *Midnight Commander* set about creating their own solution. It's similar to scp in principle, but there are more commands. The client sends commands that look like:

```
 #RETR /some/name
 ls -l /some/name | ( read a b c d x e; echo $x ); echo '### 100'; cat /some/name; echo '### 200'
```

If you're talking to a Fish server, then it will interpret the `#RETR` command. However if the remote server doesn't have a Fish server installed, the commands will be interpreted by the shell. First a comment, then a command which prints info about the file, followed by the file contents surrounded in some markers.

Effectively, in the absence of scp or Fish on the server, the client has "rolled its own" scp equivalent using shell commands - but it can equally send shell commands to rename, move, truncate, etc.

Details of Fish are in the Midnight Commander source [here](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/mc/mc/vfs/README.fish?view=markup).

What does this all mean from an end-user perspective?

- older SSH server implementations support scp but not SFTP; you can't use an SFTP client with these
- Use SFTP for performance, reliability and flexibility
- Your "scp" client might be an SFTP client in disguise (*Citation needed*)
- Fish might be useful in niche circumstances, but otherwise use the more standard SFTP.

Comment: This was the best description of these 3 protocols for file manipulation I've seen! Thank you. Using dolphin on KDE and creating a network folder I did not understand the +/- of sftp vs fish, and now I do.

Answer (score 27):

Put it simple:

```
SFTP = SSH + SFTP-server on server
SCP  = SSH + `scp` on server side
FISH = SSH + `dd` (and some other basic Unix utilities on the server side only)
```

Comment: But `sftp` and `scp` requires special programs on the server side, unlike FISH, which uses only basic Unix utuilities in the remote shell.

Comment: According to the description of FISH,a remarkable feature of FISH is that it doesn't require something special on the remote side (no server program, like `scp` for scp or sftp-server). And there're cases indeed when the remote side is a "restricted" Unix, where you can't install what you want: for transferring files to Android through SSH (over WiFi), I've written the set of [rpush-cat](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28847/13117) scripts -- perhaps, a FISH client would work. (`tramp-fish.el` in Emacs could, too: the regular TRAMP client didn't work because `stat` wasn't there on Android.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on how `scp` is also needed on the server side, in addition to the client side? With a quick google search, I couldn't find anything that confirms that `scp` is also needed on the server side.

Answer (score 12):

FISH and SFTP are similar, and as observed do both work over SSH, SFTP requires specific support and configuration in the SSH Server to facilitate the transfer, but it a bit more secure and allows for SysAdmins to only allow SFTP (in these situations FISH won't work).

FISH requires a shell (sh/rsh for instance) to copy, and hence requires full SSH access to the machine, I would imagine it would be harder to secure (I cannot comment objectively on this as I've never had to).

Where possible, I'd recommend SFTP, scp, FISH (in that order).

[Wikipedia FISH Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files_transferred_over_shell_protocol)

Comment: According to the linked description, a remarkable feature of FISH is that it doesn't require something special on the remote side (no server program, like `scp` for scp or sftp-server). And there're cases indeed when the remote side is a "restricted" Unix, where you can't install what you want: for transferring files to Android through SSH (over WiFi), I've written the set of [rpush-cat](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28847/13117) scripts -- perhaps, a FISH client would work. (`tramp-fish.el` in Emacs could, too: the regular TRAMP client didn't work because `stat` wasn't there on Android.)