# Looking for information on the FISH protocol

Tags: ssh, sshfs, fish-protocol

What I have found about `fish://` (the kio protocol) is old and often incomplete. Is there anything that's new? Like a primer? Or is this something to put on the KDE todo list?

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between SFTP, SCP and FISH protocols?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8707/whats-the-difference-between-sftp-scp-and-fish-protocols), which cites [`README.fish` in the mc CVS](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/mc/mc/vfs/README.fish?view=markup). It looks substantial, but I don't know if it's complete and up-to-date. Is it?

Comment: I checked; "Revision 1.6 - (download) (annotate)
Mon Jun 2 19:47:30 2003 UTC (8 years ago) by proskin" it's 8 years old.

Comment: The important question isn't how old it is, it's how up-to-date it is. Has the FISH protocol changed since then?

Answer (score 1):

[lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/)  supports FISH and is open source. Check the source of the FISH module, there are details of the protocol there:

https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/blob/master/src/Fish.cc