# Openssh Questions

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sshd

I was reading about OpenSSH and I have the following questions:

1. What is the difference between `ssh` and `slogin`?
2. What is the difference between `scp` and `sftp`?
3. Does `sshd` (on server side) provide separate server 
   processes to handle each client (`ssh`, `slogin`, `sftp`, `scp`) type requests or 
   just one process for all client types?
4. is the secure shell a standalone shell like `bash` etc., or just a process that encrypt/decrypts traffic and communicate to ordinary bash process locally?

Comment: All of these questions should be easily answerable by reading the relevant manuals, and by some simple testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the questions are listed, I'll list the respective answers:

1. `slogin` is an alias for `ssh` (they are the same) [further reading](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/slogin.htm)
2. `scp` and `sftp` do similar things in that they transfer files, but `scp` is a separate program that uses `ssh` to copy files.  `sftp` is an extension of `ssh` itself that transfers files similar to FTP, but over `ssh` [further reading](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8707/whats-the-difference-between-sftp-scp-and-fish-protocols)
3. Yes, the `sshd` spins up a separate process for each connection.  This can be verified by connecting multiple times to an ssh server and then doing `ps aux | grep ssh` on the server
4. `ssh` is a protocol, not a shell.  It gives access to the shell on the other side and encrypts the traffic between